# Getting Expression Type ambiguous without more context

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, healthkit

I'm trying to request authorization to use the Health app data.

I'm getting the following error:

```
FirstViewController.swift:44:9: Expression type '(typesToShare: _, readTypes: Set<HKSampleType>?, completion: (_, _) -> Void)' (aka '(typesToShare: _, readTypes: Optional<Set<HKSampleType>>, completion: (_, _) -> ())') is ambiguous without more context
```

at 44:9 where typesToShare: nil

```
let healthStore: HKHealthStore? = {
        if HKHealthStore.isHealthDataAvailable() {
            return HKHealthStore()
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }()

    let dateOfBirthCharacteristic = HKCharacteristicType.characteristicTypeForIdentifier(
        HKCharacteristicTypeIdentifierDateOfBirth)

    let biologicalSexCharacteristic = HKCharacteristicType.characteristicTypeForIdentifier(
        HKCharacteristicTypeIdentifierBiologicalSex)

    let bloodTypeCharacteristic = HKCharacteristicType.characteristicTypeForIdentifier(
        HKCharacteristicTypeIdentifierBloodType)

    let dataTypesToRead: Set<HKSampleType>? = NSSet(objects:
        dateOfBirthCharacteristic!, biologicalSexCharacteristic!, bloodTypeCharacteristic!) as? Set<HKSampleType>

    let dataTypesToShare: Set<HKSampleType>? = NSSet() as? Set<HKSampleType>

    // Making the request
    let healthData = healthStore?.requestAuthorizationToShareTypes
    (typesToShare: nil,
     readTypes: dataTypesToRead,
     completion: { (success, error) -> Void in
                                            if success {
                                                println("success")
                                            } else {
                                                println(error.description)
                                            }
    })
```

I'm new to iOS and haven't used HealthKit before. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm also new to healthKit but try using dataTypesToShare Variable at the place of nil in typesToShare argument.and better more create dataTypesToShare the same way u did with dataTypesToRead .   And this function doesn't return anything .you can try to use the closures to get the completion block success 
.

```
      func authorizeHealthKit(completion: ((success:Bool, error:NSError!) -> Void)!)
{   
healthStore?.requestAuthorizationToShareTypes
    (typesToShare: nil,
     readTypes: dataTypesToRead,
     completion: { (success, error) -> Void in
                                            if success {
                                                println("success")
                                            } else {
                                            println(error.description)
                                        }
})
}
```

Comment: you can than call this function like    , authorizeHealthKit {(success:type,error : type ) in       print("success")    }

Comment: Thanks for the reply Sourav! I tried using nil and creating typesToShare the same way as typesToRead but I'm getting the same error.

Comment: Try closure that would definetly work ,function doesn't have return type u can't use let healthdata ,  this way .

Comment: Using a closure gives me the same error and also says Expression resolved to an unused function on the line: healthStore?.request..., which is why I had the variable in the first place.